# Postgresql - Materialized views in postgres seems to be only partially updating or somehow caching old data

Tags: postgresql

so I'm working with a group that has a materialized view in postgres.
It depends on another view - lets call it A.
They've added a "refresh_time" - field which is just now() in the materialized view - so they can see when it's refreshed.

They maintain that when they run it from their machines, it works fine - and picks up the latest value from A.    However, when they run it from the server process - it refreshes fine [they can see the refresh time has changed] - but it does *not* get the latest value from A.

I believe that's completely impossible [barring a bug in postgres, and I reckon that's unlikely]- and that somehow A must not be updated when it runs - but I'm asking here if I'm wrong - is there any other way that behaviour can occur?  (eg permissions?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless there is a bug in PostgreSQL, a materialized view will never contain values older than the time when it was refreshed.

However, you should consider concurrency and multiversioning:

If a materialized views is refreshed with `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`, then the changes won't be visible until the transaction that executes the `REFRESH` statement is done. Now if two materialized views are refreshed at the same time, they won't see each other's changes. You would have to ascertain that the transaction refreshing A is committed by the time the dependent materialized view gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

ok - they found the solution - it's a bit odd - basically it was client timezone settings - and the view was getting different values in it depending on the timezone of the client who was doing the refresh - because there were some calculations dependent on dates and times with time zone.